# Application shows on part of android screen

Tags: android

I'm starting 3.1 AVD and wnen loading upplication to it the application shows fully but much smaller than actual screen like its dimentions were set statically to be smaller than the screen.

Comment: What is the minimum API level for your app?

Comment: The question is why it does not show on full screen even if i set all attributes to "fill_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Add an appropriate [`<supports-screens>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) to your manifest, and consider adding a [`<uses-sdk>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) with `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`.

If you are supporting tablet screen sizes, a likely  element would be:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="false" />
```

You could consider adding `true` for small screens as well, if you are supporting that size too.

Comment: I guess if i set all to 'true' - application will fit any screen? And if I put  appropriate images under hdpi,ldpi... folders, system will choose which  one to use according to screen resolution. Am i right?

Comment: @Mike: If you set all to `true`, that means that **you** are taking the steps to make sure that the app will run on all screen sizes (e.g., `res/layout-small/`, `res/layout-large/`). "And if I put appropriate images under hdpi,ldpi... folders, system will choose which one to use according to screen resolution" -- density, not resolution.